# When a VirtualBox VM's Adapter is set to Internal Network can the Firewall of the Host Machine Control Access to the guest VM's Ports?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine

In a VMs network settings:

1. Right click settings,
2. then in the resulting Settings dialog select `Network` from the side bar
3. And click any `Adapter N` tab,
4. If I set the `Attached to:` drop down to `Internal Network`

If I change the settings on the firewall of the host machine, will it affect the VM with a Internal Network adapter?  Or would I need another adapter?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When a VirtualBox VM's Adapter is set to NAT can a VM access the Host computer?](http://superuser.com/questions/1075627/when-a-virtualbox-vms-adapter-is-set-to-nat-can-a-vm-access-the-host-computer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will a host outside the network be able to access the internal network?

No. That's the whole point of an internal network.

> Or will I need another adapter type for that?

Yes, that would be the simplest way but another adapter might not be required. Another VM might be configured to do port forwarding, NAT or network routing and then allow remote access.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean by

> host outside the network

The **host system** (including any attached networks) and the **user**, then no, they will not be able to access it. Only other VMs on the same host which connect to the same internal network (identified by the same network `Name`) will be able to access it.

If you wish your **guest VM** to be accessible from the **host system** you can use `NAT` or `Bridged Adapter` type and (if configured correctly) even `Host-only networking`.

### NAT

Will work like attached to a `NAT` router, the **guest VM** will therefore be on a seperate subnet, different from the one on the **host system**. To be able to access a port on the guest from the host, set up a `Port Forwarding` rule, as in the examples below:

This rule will forward all packets arriving on **any interface** on the host system on port `2222` to port `22` on the guest system:

```
Name      Protocol    Host IP      Host Port    Guest IP     Guest Port
Rule 1    TCP                      2222                      22
```

This rule will forward all packets arriving on **the loopback interface only** on the host system on port `2222` to port `22` on the guest system (meaning the guest VM will only be accessible from the host system via the loopback interface and not via the host's IP):

```
Name      Protocol    Host IP      Host Port    Guest IP     Guest Port
Rule 1    TCP         127.0.0.1    2222                      22
```

If for some reason the guest uses a **static assigned IP address** not leased from the built-in DHCP server, it is required to specify the guest IP:

```
Name      Protocol    Host IP      Host Port    Guest IP     Guest Port
Rule 1    TCP         127.0.0.1    2222         10.0.2.15    22
```

In all the above examples port 22 on the guest can be accessed from the host with:

```
127.0.0.1:2222
```

### Bridged networking

When this adapter type is used, it looks to the host system as the guest were physically connected to the interface using a network cable.
The guest system will be on the same subnet as the host system in most cases.