# When a VirtualBox VM's Adapter is set to NAT can a VM access the Host computer?

Tags: networking, virtualbox

In a VMs network settings:

1. Right click settings,
2. then in the resulting Settings dialog select `Network` from the side bar
3. And click any `Adapter N` tab,
4. If I set the `Attached to:` drop down to `NAT`

Will the VM be able to access the host machine?  Does it get a specific IP with NAT?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When a VirtualBox VM's Adapter is set to Internal Network can a host outside the network access the vm?](http://superuser.com/questions/1075625/when-a-virtualbox-vms-adapter-is-set-to-internal-network-can-a-host-outside-the)

Comment: Posted 3 times... one is enough I think.. :P

Comment: Why are you asking 3 (almost) identical questions? If you have new information you should edit it into the original question instead of asking a new one.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I'm trying to fill in a grid of unanswered questions I have after reading http://blog.superuser.com/2011/04/25/virtualbox-and-networking-how-you-do-it/

Comment: :/ and apparently driving some people nuts...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you specifiy as access and what you configure for it.

Using NAT is like placing the VM in its own network and put a router in between it.

This is similar as to how your computer is shielded from a computer on the internet. Any computer on the internet that wants to have access to your pc needs their ports to be opened. Through VirtualBox's NAT interface, you can configure ports that have access from the outside to the VM and back.

More information can be found if you press the help button on the bottom right, and in the search type NAT.